# How to post more than one input field using jQuery onchange

Tags: jquery

I am trying to post 2 input fields to a PHP page using the `onchange` event. The script always returns "undefined index" error. Buy if I post 1 input, the result is successful..

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$('#name').change(function () {
  $('#pix').fadeIn();

  // run ajax request
  $.post ('chk.php',$("#name","#lname").serialize(),function(display){

    // replace div's content with returned data
    $('#cmt').val(display);;
    $('#buymsg').fadeOut(4000);

  },'text');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Show the HTML markup and the `chk.php` code.

Comment: Your question is not clear and you should provide more information. But i think the problem is with the selector syntax which should be: `$('#name, #lname')`. You should remove the double quotes around comma

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to overcome it.. instead of passing the Id of the input field individually, i passed the form entirely, and retrieved the values i need. i.e replaced $('#name, #lname')  with $('form#form'). Thank You